# arduino button doesn't work

Tags: c, arduino

So I got a program, that must turn on/off the light by a press of a button, but it just doesn't work. It doesn't show anything in the console and the light doesn't turn off/on. It just stays on for a moment of time and then turns off

```
const int buttonPin = 3;     // the number of the pushbutton pin
const int ledPin =  13;      // the number of the LED pin
int incoming = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(0, blink, CHANGE);

}

void blink()
{
  digitalWrite(ledPin, !digitalRead(buttonPin));
  if (!digitalRead(buttonPin)) {
    Serial.println("LED lights");
  } else {
    Serial.println("LED is off");
  }
}


void loop() {

  if (Serial.available() > 0) { 
    incoming = Serial.read() - 48;
    analogWrite(ledPin, incoming * 29);
    Serial.print("LED brightness = ");    
    Serial.println(incoming*29);

  }
}
```

Comment: Which board are you using?

Comment: i am using arduino uno

Answer (score 0):

In Arduino Uno, which you are using according to comments, the interrupt `0` is responsible for pin number `2` according to the [docs](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/attachInterrupt). But you are using pin `3` as your input, so according to the same page it should use interrupt `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use the interrupt? I would suggest to use a simple state pattern by comparing the previous button state like in this [code example](http://www.multiwingspan.co.uk/arduino.php?page=led4) from http://www.multiwingspan.co.uk

```
int ledPin = 13;
int buttonPin = 3;
int lastButtonState = HIGH;
int ledState = HIGH;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  // read from the button pin
  int buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  // if the button is not in the same state as the last reading
  if (buttonState==LOW && buttonState!=lastButtonState)
  {
    // change the LED state
    if (ledState==HIGH)
    {
      ledState = LOW;
    }
    else
    {
      ledState = HIGH;
    }
  }
  digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
  // store the current button state
  lastButtonState = buttonState;
  // add a delay to avoid multiple presses being registered
  delay(20);
}
```

Comment: have you checked all pins and the circuit as described in the link "code example"?